# What is the purpose for registering multuple PrintPageEventHandlers to PrintDocument's PrintPage?

Tags: c#, events, printing

If I register two separate PrintPageEventHandler's and print, then the first event fires off and prints the pages, and then the second event fires and starts from the beginning, printing over the original text.

What I currently understand is if I register one event, and set PrintPageEventArgs.HasMorePages = true, the event is recalled upon exit and a new page is started. So calling g.DrawString (where g is PrintPageEventArgs.Graphics) some how informs the back end that any further graphics will be on a separate page.

Now, if I register two events.. The first event prints fine with separate pages as declared, but then when the second event is called, everything is reset to the original starting point, and the second event's drawstring() writes over the first creating a garbled mess. So where there should have been 6 pages, only 3 are printed with information from both events.

What am I doing wrong?

here is a sample of my code logic.

```
PrintItem<Progress> printItem = new PrintItem<Progress>(list);

using (Printer printer = new Printer(printerName))
{
   printer.registerPrintJob(getClosingSummaryPrintEvent(printItem));
   printer.registerPrintJob(getClosingSummaryPrintEventPartsCompleted(printItem));
   if (!printer.Print(errors))
   {
     //...error message
   }
}
```

Printer is a custom class that inherits PrintDocument

and this is what the register print job methods looks like for clarity.

```
 public void registerPrintJob(PrintPageEventHandler pd_PrintPage)
 {
  this.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;
 }
```

What I am trying to accomplish:
I am using one event to print a summary page that prints a list of errors. Setting HasMorePages = true conditionally will continue the list onto a new page (if necessary), and is set back to false when the end of the list is reached. The second event, is a follow on that prints different, but related data in a different format. I figure this was the idea behind multiple events. If I am incorrect, and a separate event added will just write over the first, then is there ever a point to adding two events? If so then why?